# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loading'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I fix this warning?

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loading'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && data) {
      dispatch(action.TODO(data));
    }
  }, [data, dispatch]);
```

Comment: It tells you how to fix it: Either include `loading` to your dependency array or remove the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a dependency to a `useEffect` hook by specifying it in the second argument array.

Like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!loading && data) {
     dispatch(action.TODO(data));
  }
}, [data, dispatch, loading]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: in the array of the second parameter of `useEffect` remove `dispatch` and add `loading`

The correct answer is:
When `useEffect` uses a variable as a conditional inside its execution, it considers it a dependency, and indicates that it should be executed again when it is being modified, otherwise it must be eliminated from the dependencies array

Answer (score 0):

You are making use of `useEffect` and you are going to want to frequently refer to some variables declared as props or state inside of your component. You are already doing that with `data`. That is a piece of state that you are referring to inside your `useEffect` function.

`loading` is either a prop or a piece of state and when you are referring to a prop or a piece of state there is a rule written into ESLint specifically that wants you to reference any piece of prop or piece of state inside of `useEffect` dependency array. That controls when `useEffect` gets executed and that rule wants to see listed inside the dependency array the prop or piece of state you are referencing.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!loading && data) {
     dispatch(action.TODO(data));
  }
}, [data, dispatch, loading]);
```

Why does that rule want us to put that `loading` in there? There are some scenarios where making use of `useEffect` and not referencing the prop or piece of state inside the dependency can lead to some weird and hard to debug problems.

So that warning is all about helping you avoid hard to understand problems when making use of `useEffect`.

While that rule is well-intentioned, arbitrarily adding in so many rules to the dependency array can potentially lead to other bugs, just something to be aware of.